# Open a file without any extension

Tags: file, notepad++

I have a file from a farming maskin, I know that some files where .csv files, I found one to be a database file, hence this I have no clue.. It had no extension and was named just the fieldname + "_data". I tried to open it with Notepad++, and then it looked like this:

[image: Error File]

Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't ask the creator?

Comment: Hehe, They are hard to get in touch with and, honestly I doubt they know :)

Comment: almost no one can conclude what that is just by looking at a binary file as text. If the format is wellknown, `file` command on Linux can help

Comment: Could have worked.. I tried `file THE_FILENAME` on a Linux computer hence it just returned `data`